How would the Aboriginal Australians interact with and utilize a Sapient Octopus Species?
Continuation of
Large Sapient Octopus: How could they survive in warm waters?
Is there enough food in the Ocean to support large populations of Octopus?
Your answers were helpful in developing this little hobby world of mine, thank you all :]. Over the past few months I have been doing a bit of research, a bit of daydreaming, a bit of 'worldbuilding' overall on this Sapient Octopus species, and of course a copious ludicrous absurd amount of changing rewriting and revising what info/lore I have written down.
As of now, the sapient octopus species are called the "Marites", physically they are the proportions of the Giant Pacific Octopus. They live on the Eastern, Southern, and Western(but not Northern)coasts of Australia and maybe New Zealand too. They tolerate temperatures in a large range from around 5 C to 25 C.
They arent very social, just like real life octopuses, but they interact through writing and body-color-language when they bump into each other or when needed. They live alone and sometimes close together in places called "Consortiums" where favorable environments created by previous Marite inhabitants attract a bunch of Marites to live in the same area. When there is something for both parties to gain, trade is also undergone.

Oh right! Sorry.
So these Marites live and evolved in the coasts of Australia. But 40,000 years ago, the first humans get to the continent. And in the timeline of this world, these interactions between the Aboriginal Australians and the Marites will be important.
Obviously, the first interactions would fall into two categories, those of hostility, where they'd try to eat each other and cut off access to each other's domain. And those of benevolence where they maybe do some trade, or maybe with Marites helping the Australians fish.
What do the Marites have to trade? Well fish and shellfish for one, as it is a big source of food. They also cultivated/bred corals into many varieties for many different purposes (One type may be lightweight and strong for armor, one type may easily be broken into sharp pieces for spear tips, etc.). What would they trade for? Humans have Obsidian, which doesn't form underwater as far as I can tell, and would make a good sharper upgrade to the coral spear tips. Food from land animals could also be delicious. Most of all things that require drying out would be desirable to the Marites, due to the difficulty of making it themselves, fire-products especially would be wanted.
But this is a simple overview I have based on my info I have so far, and this is just the first interactions. What I want to know is how these interactions would evolve, what complex interactions might Aboriginal Australians and Marites have?
Essentially, what creative ways could you think of that Marites and Australians could interact? How would the Marites be helpful/useful or harmful to the Aboriginal Australians and vice versa?

We are not a brainstorming site. Furthermore we are not here to tell you how events in your world will play out. If you are asking about what a character or group of people will do in a scenario, it is not permitted here.

Obsidian is very very rare in Australia. There's not much good knapping stone at all.

A silly suggestion that may pay off for you: try our [conlang.se] site for further suggestions.

"How would the Aboriginal Australians interact with and utilize a Sapient Octopus Species?" - "what creative ways could you think of that Marites and Australians could interact?" - this is both story-based and opinion-based.

VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help]. Questions about the actions, decisions and motivations of individuals and/or organizations are prohibited. The problem is that questions involving characters are inevitably opinion-based (all answers having equal value), open-ended, and story-based (meaning story circumstances are all that's needed for any answer to be valid, aka "hypothetical") - all of which is prohibited in the [help].

Vote to close: “brainstorm list of options” is explicitly banned question as it has no right answer. Move to Reddit, Quora or similar discussion forum.

Homo sapiens has met up with sapient species before. They're all extinct. There was some sexual contact, but that won't work with octopi. Aborigine were in Sahul a lot longer than 40 thousand years.
Aborigines do not need anything from your octopuses or vice versa. They're both predators competing for the same seafood. So we'd hunt or avoid the octopi if we could just like any other dangerous sea creature at first. Maybe a long time later we'd have a go at domesticating them. But we'd never opt for an even partnership. We never have.
It doesn't need to be us though. It would be a nice idea to have some Denisovans who over a couple of hundred thousand years became somewhat aquatic and started a relationship with the octopi. Then when humans displaced/absorbed them they basically just continued the relationship.

We can trade- and trade allows for specialization of labor. The aborigines could trade fertilizer and minerals, which can grow algea. Algea feeds plankton, plankton feeds fish, the man in the canoo brings the source of food, the octopus trade back fish once its all grown up. Its farming.

Outsiders are outside the AA gender, clan, and lineage systems. For some groups that makes them convenient for storing / holding sacred objects (the nuclear waste of the AA origin/food/health/birth/death spiritual system), as intermediaries in prohibited relationships, permitted to cross tribal boundaries, and non-aligned in situations where traditional AA clan members are required to prioritize internal relationships.
This includes situations where traditional AA would be prohibited from talking to each other and situations where they would be required to annex goods for tribal distribution.
